# Python on Windows: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, rabbitmq

Someone setup [rabbitmqadmin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) on Windows and now when we run the job which shall create the queues, the script fails due do an ssl problem

```
11:27:12 Traceback (most recent call last):
11:27:12   File "D:\jenkins\home\workspace\RabbitMQ-BUILD\target\classes\rabbitmqadmin", line 535, in http
11:27:12     conn.request(method, path, body, headers)
11:27:12   File "http\client.py", line 1239, in request
11:27:12   File "http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
11:27:12   File "http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
11:27:12   File "http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
11:27:12   File "http\client.py", line 964, in send
11:27:12   File "http\client.py", line 1400, in connect
11:27:12   File "ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
11:27:12   File "ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
11:27:12   File "ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
11:27:12   File "ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
11:27:12 ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)
11:27:12 
11:27:12 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
11:27:12 
11:27:12 Traceback (most recent call last):
11:27:12   File "D:\jenkins\home\workspace\RabbitMQ-BUILD\target\classes\rabbitmqadmin", line 1066, in <module>
11:27:12     main()
11:27:12   File "D:\jenkins\home\workspace\RabbitMQ-BUILD\target\classes\rabbitmqadmin", line 447, in main
11:27:12     method()
11:27:12   File "D:\jenkins\home\workspace\RabbitMQ-BUILD\target\classes\rabbitmqadmin", line 638, in invoke_list
11:27:12     format_list(self.get(uri), cols, obj_info, self.options)
11:27:12   File "D:\jenkins\home\workspace\RabbitMQ-BUILD\target\classes\rabbitmqadmin", line 477, in get
11:27:12     return self.http("GET", "%s/api%s" % (self.options.path_prefix, path), "")
11:27:12   File "D:\jenkins\home\workspace\RabbitMQ-BUILD\target\classes\rabbitmqadmin", line 537, in http
11:27:12     traceback.print_exc(e)
11:27:12   File "traceback.py", line 159, in print_exc
11:27:12   File "traceback.py", line 100, in print_exception
11:27:12   File "traceback.py", line 497, in __init__
11:27:12   File "traceback.py", line 332, in extract
11:27:12 TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'ssl.SSLError' and 'int'
```

When I check the ssl config there I see some path (openssl_cafile, openssl_capath) which apparently do not exist in Windows

```
>>> print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs')
```

Unfortunately I am python and rabbitmq newbie and as I did not setup the whole thing I am stuck. I try to understand how to fix the the problems so the ssl error does not occur anymore

1. what is wrong configured
2. where do you configure certification path in python for windows

**Here is what I know:**

We use self-signed certificates (have to).

ssl related config in rabbitmq.config looks as follows

```
 {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,           "D:\\RabbitMQ\\rabbitmqca.pem"},
            {certfile,             "D:\\RabbitMQ\\myhost_listener.pem"},
            {keyfile,              "D:\\RabbitMQ\\myhost_listener_key.pem"},
            {verify,               verify_peer},
            {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]},
```

Comment: Is the self-signed certificate generated on the same computer you are trying to connect to it? It sure looks like a certificate authority issue, and self-signed almost certainly confirms it.

Comment: The self-signed certificate is signed by an internal CA and that's fine. Just need a way to tell python how to trust these certificates. In Java I can specify a trust store with the internal root CA in it. No clue how this works with Python

Comment: Usually that is done through the OS, so ensure your windows box contains the proper root CA chain.

Comment: All required root certificates are one the box under "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"